# What happens to push notifications after losing internet access?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What happens if an application is waiting for a push notification and the internet connection is unavailable?

For example, I tell my server to do task "A", and notify me via APNS when the task is ready. But, after I send the task to the server, the application loses internet connectivity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notification will be delivered when internet connection on iPhone becomes available again.

> Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS
>   stores the notification. It retains only one notification per
>   application on a device: the last notification received from a
>   provider for that application. When the offline device later
>   reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device.
>   The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting
>   it.

See "Quality of Service" section of [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when sending PUSHes with own server API, and also take into account `apns-expiration` field in APNs Provider API payload.

> This header identifies the date when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded...
>
> ...if the **value is 0**, APNs treats the notification as if it **expires
>   immediately and does not store** the notification or attempt to
>   redeliver it...

[By Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW15).

It can be the reason, that the push notification does not come after network connection was restored.