# iOS silent notification internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, push-notification

I would like to know how to implement silent notifications that will only load the app and reschedule local notifications if the user does not have an internet connection? Is it possible or silent notifications won't be received unless there is internet connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007880/what-happens-to-push-notifications-after-losing-internet-access

Answer (score 0):

Silent Push Notification won't be received unless there is internet connection.
Silent Push Notification send by server.